# Why does the Sun track out a seemingly sinusoidal path on the celestial sphere?

Tags: celestial-mechanics, ecliptic-plane

I know it's somehow related to the way things are projected but it hasn't quite clicked yet. The question arose because I wanted to understand the path of the eclipitic after reading about it here: http://community.dur.ac.uk/john.lucey/users/solar_year.html

Comment: Which bit don't you understand? Because of the Earths axial tilt, the sun is higher in the sky during summer, and lower in winter. May be more appropriate in Astronomy.

Comment: Right, so it’s the axial tilt that causes the sinusoidal path? If earth wasn’t tilted would that mean the sun would track a straight path on the celestial sphere? 
Yes you’re right this probably belongs in Astronomy. Will post there. And this can be closed.

Comment: @keynes you can ask in Astronomy by clicking edit here and copying the text, and pasting it in a new question in Astronomy SE once you join, but don't forget to delete it here. The other and more proper way is (now that it's closed) to flag for moderator assistance to migrate to astronomy.